# Cannot use Go to file feature in NetBeans with files in Include Path

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.2

I'd like to use the Go to files feature in NetBeans for the files in Include Path, but I cannot. Is there anyway to turn it on or it's just not implemented? I'm using NetBeans 7.2 for PHP.

Thanks,